# Can I draw attention to a well deserving answer on my question?

Tags: discussion, answers

Earlier today I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380789/what-are-the-major-performance-hitters-in-as3-aside-from-rendering-vectors) which yielded a [really well-done answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8380883/447356).

I'd like to attract attention to this answer in the hope that the answer will get upvoted, as a kind of reward for the quality of the answer.

Is there anything that I can do to achieve this?

Comment: did you consider giving a [bounty](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bounty)? _"A bounty is a way to get additional attention for a question by offering some of your own reputation for great answers."_ If not - why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you just did. :)

Seriously though, apart of posting here you can also wait two days and grant that answer a Bounty, taking anywhere from 50 to 500 of your own reputation.

One of the bounty reasons is "Reward existing answer":

> [image]

Comment: Interesting, never knew that bounties had a use aside from forcing attention to a difficult or untouched question - thanks! I also updated the answer I was referring to with some links added and the SO formatted list to improve it and move it to the homepage temporarily.

Comment: Yeah, adding bounty reason is pretty new feature and makes it easier to explain why you start the bounty. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 9):

You can add a bounty to your question and give it to the deserving answer.

This will essentially transfer your reputation to the one who answered.

Answer (score 7):

You could also post a link to the question on Twitter, Facebook, et al.

Comment: You can also post a link directly to the answer (which may make sense in the context of, say, a blog post along the lines of "I was having trouble with such and such, and then I got this really cool tip...").

Answer (score 0):

Reference it from a question on meta!

Comment: While that certainly works in this case, I don't think this is something we want to encourage. MSO is busy enough without filling up the front page with "check out this answer" non-questions.